# Do lighters ever run out of fuel?

Tags: neo-scavenger

I've found a ton of lighters, but they don't seem to be one-time use like I expected. Do they ever run out, or should I drop the rest and just start carrying around one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do.

One of the stats on lighters is `Charges`.  I haven't actually used a lighter yet, but presumably, using one in combinations (with sticks, tinder, or whatnot), will reduce the charges available in the lighter.

Comment: The number of charges is the most important factor in determining the *value* of a lighter, rather than the condition its in, so this is probably a pretty important number.

Comment: Also if you use lighter under the rain without any cover like tent of building, lighter charges drop to zero.